# Using split/join to replace a string with an array

Tags: javascript, string, join, replace, split

I'm trying to replace the value of `item` with values ​​in the array `arr`, but I only get that if I use: `arr [1]`, `arr [2]` ...  if I just let
 `arr`, returns `abcdefg`.

I am PHP programmer, and I have a minimal
notion with JavaScript, can someone give me a light?

```
var item = 'abcdefg';
var arr = new Array();
arr[1] = "zzz";
arr[2] = "abc";
var test = item.split(arr);
alert(test.join("\n"));
```

Comment: Please be clearer on what your trying to do.

Comment: Please give an example of what `item` should contain when this has completed. Should `item` look like `zzzabc` or `zzzdefg` or something else entirely?

Comment: HMM return the string item '1' to -> 'zzz', or item '2' to -> 'xxx'...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
var item = 'Hello, 1, my name is 2.';
var arr = new Array();
arr [1] = 'admin';
arr [2] = 'guest';
for (var x in arr)
    item = item.replace(x, arr[x]);
alert(item);
```

It produces:

```
Hello, admin, my name is guest.
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is replace the IDs with names, example:

id 1 - admin
id 2 - guest
id 3 - test1
id 4 - test2

These values​​, I would have in an array (arr [1] = admin, arr [2] = guest, etc.), the string value item, would be the id, so I searched the id in the array array and replace the name .

Comment: you may need to do foreach item in array, do replacement.

Comment: can you help me with this? :(

Comment: @GtOkAi, I added some code.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! It would only be to the contrary, changing the admin change by 1 and 2 per guest

Comment: @GtOkAi, I changed the sample.

Comment: Yeah! I had managed to make the change, thank you! I feel obligated now studying JS. Thanks again, helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Split uses regular expressions, so

```
"My String".split('S') == ["My ","tring"]
```

If you are trying to replace a string:

```
"abcdef".replace('abc','zzz') == "zzzdef"
```

Comment: It uses regular expressions, i.e. `/[a-z]+/` *or* strings, i.e. `"/[a-z]+/"`. The former splits on any block of lower-case letters, the latter on the literal string `/[a-z]+/`.

Comment: [`split` was deprecated in PHP 5.3 and removed in PHP 7.0](https://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php). Perhaps time for an update?